# Get generated bar colour dynamically

Tags: angularjs, charts, zingchart

Is there any way to generate bar colours dynamically in ZingChart?
in screen-shot there is two colours generated in bar chart, i want to get list of colors used in bar chart.
[image]

> html file

```
<zingchart id="timesheet-bar-chart" zc-values="barValues" zc-  json="myObj"></zingchart>
```

> controller

```
$scope.myObj = {
  "type": "bar",
  "plot":{
    "stacked":true,
    "stack-type":"normal" /* Optional specification */
  },
 "scale-x":{
      "transform":{
        "type":"date",
        "all":"%d %M",
        "item": {
          "visible":false
        }
      },
     "values":$scope.bar_x_axis,
    },
  };
```

and barValues is a list of integer values.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: @Sajeetharan I have posted code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your question is asking how to get the bar colors, not set the bar colors. I thought my answer would be appropriate as well.

You can use the API to [getobjectinfo](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/methods/#zingchart__exec__api__getobjectinfo) from the chart.

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/6n10snmg/)

```
    $scope.myRender = {  
    events : {  
        complete : function(p) {  
            var info1 = zingchart.exec(p.id, 'getobjectinfo', {
              object : 'plot',
              plotindex: 0
          });
            var info2 = zingchart.exec(p.id, 'getobjectinfo', {
              object : 'plot',
              plotindex: 1
          });
          console.log(info1, info2);
        }  
    }  
}
```

If youre confused on the `$scope.myRender` variable you can read up more on the angular directive [here](https://blog.zingchart.com/2015/03/05/zingchart-angularjs/?q=zingchart%20and%20angularjs).

Answer (score 3):

You can set the colors like this,

```
$scope.myJson = {
        'plot': {
        'styles': ['#yellow', 'red', 'blue']
      },
      'scale-x': {
        'values': ['white', 'red', 'pink']
      },
      'type': 'bar',
      'series': [{
        'text': 'Product History Color',
        'values': [2, 6, 8]
      }]
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/g6oqabx8/)**

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the colors, fonts etc by yourself.

e.g.

```
scaleX: {
  labels: ['Facebook','Apple', 'Microsoft', 'Intel','Google', 'Amazon'],
  item: {
    fontFamily: "Roboto",
    fontSize: 14
  },
  lineColor: "#DDD",
  tick:{
    visible: false
  }
},
```